# I want to submit values in database and retrieve these values in table format but not get the proper result. Tell me the correct code

Tags: php

I have a piece of code which have design for submitting and retrieving values from Database in Table Format 
I have design a page whose validations are working properly but when i write code for submit values in Database it it is not showing any row in Database

```
<head>
<title>Sunil1</title>
</head>
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','')or die("Unable to create to connection");
mysql_select_db("sunil") or die(mysql_error());
$Name1=$_POST["t1"];
$Name2=$_POST["t2"];
$Sex=$_POST["sex"];
$Country=$_POST["Country"];
$Hobby=$_POST["check"];
$Email=$_POST["t3"];
$Pass=$_POST["p1"];
$Repass=$_POST["p2"];
$sql="INSERT INTO registration (First_Name,Last_Name,Sex,Country,Hobbies,Email,Password,Repassword) VALUES('$Name1',$Name2','$Sex','$Country','$Hobby','$Email','$Pass','$Repass')";
mysql_query($sql);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)):
        $Name1=$row['First_Name'];
        $Name2=$row['Last_Name'];
        $Sex=$row['Sex'];
        $Country=$row['Country'];
        $Hobby=$row['Hobbies'];
        $Email=$row['Email'];
        $Pass=$row['Password'];
        $Repass=$row['Repassword'];
    echo"$Name1<br>$Name2<br>$Sex<br>$Country<br>$Hobby<br>$Email<br>$Pass<br>$Repass";
endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: First, can you check if you have entries in your table ? Via phpmyadmin or any other tool. Second, use php PDO instead of old mysql_* functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey you have missed opening ' for last name value
Try your query like this it should work

```
$sql="INSERT INTO registration (First_Name,Last_Name,Sex,Country,Hobbies,Email,Password,Repassword) VALUES('$Name1','$Name2','$Sex','$Country','$Hobby','$Email','$Pass','$Repass')";
```

Comment: Thanks for this but one error is still coming data is not showed in table form it comes two times and line by line. Please give answer

Comment: When i submitting the form values from Database are showing like this not in Table manner                                        Sunil
Pachlangia
Male
USA
Football                                    sunilpachlangia@ymail.com
123456789
123456789